# Add dependency to specific productFlavor and buildType in gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle

I'm wondering how to add dependency to specific productFlavor and buildType in gradle.
For example I have productFlavor `free` and build type `release`, how can I add a dependency on the `assembleFreeRelease` task?

I've tried many variants but neither works.

For example I tried:

```
task('release', dependsOn: assembleProductionRelease) {
} 
// error: Could not find property 'assembleProductionRelease' on root project 'app'.
```

Or:

```
task('release', dependsOn: 'assembleProductionRelease') {
}
```

Here there is no error but the task is executed for every flavor and build type, very confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These task are generated dynamically based on your Android plugin configuration. At the time of configuration they are not available to you yet. You can defer the creation of your task in two ways:

*Wait until the [project is evaluated](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate(groovy.lang.Closure)).*

```
afterEvaluate {
    task yourTask(dependsOn: assembleFreeRelease) {
        println "Your task"
    }
}
```

*[Lazily declaring the task dependency](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:task_dependencies) as String.*

```
task yourTask(dependsOn: 'assembleFreeRelease') {
    println "Your task"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

There is built-in support for flavor and buildType dependencies.

```
dependencies {
   flavor1Compile "..."
   freeReleaseCompile "..."
}
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: this works if your dependencies block is after the android block

Comment: But how do you combine flavors with buildTypes e.g. flavor1DebugCompile or flavor1ReleaseCompile. It doesn't work for me

Comment: To support "flavorBuildTypeCompile" you need to declare "configurations" block with appropriate configuration name "flavorBuildTypeCompile", see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28993581/3256989

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies:

"However, if you want to add a dependency for a variant that combines a product flavor and a build type, then you must initialize the configuration name in the configurations block. The following sample adds a runtimeOnly dependency to your "freeDebug" build variant (using a local binary dependency):"

Answer (score 8):

Looks like now in version 1 of the android gradle plugin and gradle 2.2+, you can do this with a configuration:

```
configurations {
  freeReleaseCompile
}

android {
   ...
  productFlavors {
    free {
      ...
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  freeReleaseCompile('myLib@aar')
}
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/E2H_rNyO6-o/h-zFJso-ncoJ

Comment: This is still correct. Compile can be replaced by `Implementation` if someone wants to use implementation instead of compile.

Answer (score 3):

*Muschko's answer didn't work for me, so this is my solution, written and posted by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743664/774398)*

Define the task that should only be executed on a specific buildType/variant/flavor

```
task doSomethingOnWhenBuildProductionRelease << {
    //code
}
```

It's important to use the "<<" syntax or else the task will automatically be called every time.

Dynamically set the dependency when the tasks are added by gradle

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleProductionRelease') {
        task.dependsOn doSomethingOnWhenBuildProductionRelease 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    ext.addDependency = {
        task, flavor, dependency ->
            def taskName = task.name.toLowerCase(Locale.US)
            if (taskName.indexOf(flavor.toLowerCase(Locale.US)) >= 0) {
                task.dependsOn dependency
            }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
        }
        other
    }

    task theProductionTask << {
        println('only in production')
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> addDependency compileTask, "production", theProductionTask
    }
}
```

To be frank, I don't which locale is used to generate names for compile taks so `toLowerCase(Locale.US)` may be counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that I used:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {  
    compileTask ->  
    def dependedTaskName = "dependedTask_";  
    if(compileTask.name.contains('Release') {  
      dependedTaskName += "Release";  
    }  
    createTask(dependedTaskName, Exec) {  
     ........  
    }  

    compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuildTaskName  
}
```

Another way:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->  
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildTypeBuildConfig') {  
        task.dependsOn doSomethingForReleaseBuild   
    }  
}
```

The 1st method is dynamic while the second one is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> Update: This solution no longer works as of 12/8/2022
>
> I now get the error message: No such property: productFlavors for class: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty

All the above answers helped me, but I ended up needing to run a script before the compilation of each flavor's debug + release build. The first argument of the script takes the flavor name.

In order to have this trigger early on, but after the flavor specific task has been created, the key is binding the dependsOn to generateMyflavorDebugBuildConfig.

Here's the script I ended up with, which can be placed at the bottom of app/build.gradle

```
// When a task is active, loop through all app flavors, and see if the 
// task.name matches the earliest task we can set up the dependsOn

// loop through all flavors, and create a task that does the work we want to do 
// before anything else
android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
    task("${flavor.name}RunCommandBefore", type: Exec) {
        workingDir "$projectDir/../.."
        commandLine 'sh', 'scripts/run_thing.sh', "${flavor.name}"
    }
}

// when tasks created, loop through and as early as we can, bind the 
// RunCommandBefore task we created above
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def taskName = task.name
    // loop through all flavors
    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        def flavorName = flavor.name 
        // loop through release types so that this happens for debug and release
        ['debug', 'release'].each { releaseType -> 
            // generateMyflavorDebugBuildConfig is the earliest task we're able  
            // to set up the dependsOn to make sure that our script runs 
            if (taskName.toLowerCase() == "generate${flavorName.toLowerCase()}${releaseType}buildconfig") {
                // now myflavorRunCommandBefore will run before 
                // generateMyflavorDebugBuildConfig
                tasks."$taskName".dependsOn "${flavorName}RunCommandBefore"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone! Amazing how difficult Android makes running a simple script first thing..