# In Android/Gradle how to define a task that only runs when building specific buildType/buildVariant/productFlavor (v0.10+)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Plugin for Gradle generates for every BuilType/Flavor/BuildVariant a task. The problem is that this task will be generated dynamically and thus won't be available as a dependency when defining a task like this:

```
task myTaskOnlyForDebugBuildType(dependsOn:assembleDebug) {
    //do smth
}
```

A proposed workaround from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598746/774398) would be this

```
task myTaskOnlyForDebugBuildType(dependsOn:"assembleDebug") {
    //do smth
}
```

or this

```
afterEvaluate {
    task myTaskOnlyForDebugBuildType(dependsOn:assembleDebug) {
        //do smth
    }
}
```

But both didn't work for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Here is a full example on how to do this [inspired by this post](http://www.jayway.com/2013/02/26/using-gradle-for-building-android-applications/):** *(android plugin v.0.9.2 and gradle 1.11 at the time of writing)*

We are going to define a task that only runs when we build a "debugCustomBuildType"

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debugCustomBuildType {
            //config
        }
   }
}
```

Define the task that should only be executed on a specific builtType/variant/flavor

```
task doSomethingOnWhenBuildDebugCustom {
    doLast {
       //task action
    }
}
```

Dynamically set the dependency when the tasks are added by gradle

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateDebugCustomBuildTypeBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn doSomethingOnWhenBuildDebugCustom 
    }
}
```

Here we use the "generateBuildConfig" task, but you can use any task that works for you ([also see official docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manipulating-tasks))

- processManifest
- aidlCompile
- renderscriptCompile
- mergeResourcess.
- mergeAssets
- processResources
- generateBuildConfig
- javaCompile
- processJavaResources
- assemble

Don't forget to use the buildTypeSpecific task (`generateBuildConfig` vs. `generateDebugCustomBuildTypeBuildConfig`)

And that's it. It's a shame this workaround isn't well documented because for me this seems like one of the simplest requirements for a build script.

Comment: Does this have to be run from command line?  Or does Android Studio run these when you press the green "Run" button?

Comment: Depending on the buildType. Usually the green "Run" button builds the debug buildType, if you have set up your actions for this buildType it will be executed - no need for "command line run"

Answer (score 7):

I achieved it like this:

```
android {
    ext.addDependency = {
        task, flavor, dependency ->
            def taskName = task.name.toLowerCase(Locale.US)
            if (taskName.indexOf(flavor.toLowerCase(Locale.US)) >= 0) {
                task.dependsOn dependency
            }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
        }
        other
    }

    task theProductionTask << {
        println('only in production')
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> addDependency compileTask, "production", theProductionTask
    }
}
```

To be frank, I don't which locale is used to generate names for compile taks so `toLowerCase(Locale.US)` may be counterproductive.

Comment: I dont know of any android gradle task that includes non-ascii chars and if you keep your names also simple ommiting special chars toLowerCase(Locale.US) should be safe.

Comment: This worked for me as well when I had to write values in a custom properties file outside the module dir.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
afterEvaluate {
    if (project.hasProperty("preReleaseBuild")){
        tasks.preReleaseBuild.dependsOn bundleJSRelease
    } else {
        tasks.preDebugBuild.dependsOn bundleJSDebug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.contains("assembleRelease")) {
        task.getDependsOn().add({
            // add your logic here
        })
    }
}
```