# How to use a different library according the build in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have 3 jar files in my Android project's app/libs folder:
**api-dev.jar

api-qa.jar

api-prod.jar**

I want to use **api-dev.jar** when I work on the app in the studio (default), build a version of the app using **api-qa.jar** which will be tested by the QA team, then release the production app with **api-prod.jar**.

How should I do?

So far I read that I should add a

```
configurations {
    qaCompile
    ...
}
```

element to app/build.gradle and use

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        ...
        qa {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

to define the builds.
I don't know how to point to the appropriate libs/dependencies, I don't know how to make one the default one either, especially in my case where the default one is not the one for the production release...

Also if the API requires a specific key for dev, qa and prod, how do I set it up?

By the way the features are exactly the same between the different builds, the user experience is exactly the same, it's why I want to use builds, not flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - [Add dependency to specific productFlavor and buildType in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589342/add-dependency-to-specific-productflavor-and-buildtype-in-gradle)

1. Add you jars to the libs directory
2. Create a build type and product flavor
3. Use the name to create a specific compile command
4. Use that to specify your jar file in the libs directory