# How can I include a library project in only the Premium build of my app and not the Free build?

Tags: android, android-library

I have an App which uses the same code base for the Paid and Free versions..

The cut-down `build.gradle` below gives an idea of the structure

```
android {
....
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myco.myapp"
    ....
}

buildTypes {
....
    release {
    ....
    }
}

productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PREMIUM", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "FREE", "true"
    }
    premium {
        applicationIdSuffix ".premium"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PREMIUM", "true"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "FREE", "false"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ....
    compile project(path: ':LVL')
}
```

I am calling the LVL licencing in `onCreate` as follows :-

```
        if (BuildConfig.PREMIUM) {
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID;
        Log.i(TAG, "Device Id: " + deviceId);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
        // Construct the LicenseChecker with a Policy.
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
                getApplicationContext(), new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  // Your public licensing key.
        );
        doCheck();
    }
```

The LVL library isn't called or required in the 'free' version of `myapp`. My question is :- how should I structure my project / `build.gradle` so that the LVL library isn't included in the APK of the Free version (but is included in the Premium version?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dependencies {
   premiumCompile project(':LVL')
}
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589342/add-dependency-to-specific-productflavor-and-buildtype-in-gradle) to similar question

Comment: Thank you. This does answer my specific question. However, I've decided that there's so much work involved in either implementing a dummy "LVL" class, or rearranging MainActivity into 'free' and 'premium' flavors so as to remove calls to LVL from the 'free' version, that it's not worth the trouble. So I'll just include LVL in both builds since the overhead is relatively small.