# Execute multiple tasks before assembleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two tasks, a `test`-task and a `poeditorPull`-task (which pulls the latest strings from the poeditor-api) and I want my assembleRelease-task to run after both have finished.

So far, I've used `task.dependsOn`, but yesterday I found out that gradle finishes building the apk before the poeditorPull-task finishes

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name == 'assembleInternalRelease' || task.name == 'assembleProductionRelease') {
    task.dependsOn('test')
    task.dependsOn('poeditorPull')
  }
}
```

As I said earlier, this doesn't do what I want, namely enqueue the tasks `test` and `poeditorPull` before `assemble*Release`

how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have re-phrased my answer to make it more concise and clear...

Problem is that `assemble*` tasks are created dynamically by Android plugin, so in your build script you cannot reference directly these tasks. You should use `afterEvaluate` block :it will be executed after all tasks have been created, so you will be able to create dependency from 'assembleInternalRelease' to your own tasks

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    assembleInternalRelease.dependsOn tasks.getByName('test')
    // or tasks.getByName('assembleInternalRelease').dependsOn tasks.getByName('test')
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding the following code https://gist.github.com/TormundsMember/2f74cd708e02e460fde909cc57ea4c37, gradle didn't recognize the tasks, the internet told me to put them in quotation-marks, which means that now i'm working with strings inside the lambda. thanks for trying to help though, much appreciated

Comment: what is the error message you get?   else you can try to use "tasks.getByName(String taskName)" instead, it should work (edited my answser with the other syntax)

Comment: apparently, the android-plugin doesn't know the tasks `assembleReleaseInternal` and `assembleReleaseProduction`. `gradlew tasks` only displays `assembleRelease`. I've tried all three variants, the Android Gradle Plugin in Android Studio doesn't recognize either of them. I'm guessing that's a bug with the android plugin itself

Comment: one suggestion, in order to confirm my assumption: can you try to move your initial code block `tasks.whenTaskAdded { ... }` before the line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` ?  It should normally create the dependencies properly.. to be confirmed.

Comment: it behaves the same way it does when the block is below the plugin-stuff. I assume that the `assemble`-task is too late in the chain (in fact, it's the last task that's executed). I guess I have to hook into a different task

Comment: or try solution in my second edit ( `afterEvaluated()` block ) ;  your issue seems also similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589342/add-dependency-to-specific-productflavor-and-buildtype-in-gradle/19598746#19598746 . The fact that `assemble-` task are the last task executed should not be a problem at all : Gradle will take into account all your dependencies constraints when creating the task graph. the main problem here is that your constraint is not properly added to existing tasks .

Answer (score 1):

as it turns out, the code was working fine, but since the plugin works asynchronously, it's impossible to have my task wait on completion

@M.Ricciuti sorry for wasting your time, thanks nonetheless